# The type must be a reference type to be used as a parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I get this compile error

> The type 'TEntiy' must be a reference type in order to use it a parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet'.

When used in this method:

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> Search<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] include)
{
    var dbSet = dataContext.Set<TEntity>();

    var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>, IQueryable<TEntity>>
                (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

    return set.Where(predicate);
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: can you post the class definition for `TEntity` ?

Comment: Add the generic type constraint `where TEntity : class` to the signature of your method.

Comment: @heijp06 It works! Add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DbSet<TEntity>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) type requires its type argument to be a reference type. You can ensure this is the case by adding a generic type constraint:

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> Search<TEntity>(...) where TEntity : class
{
    ...
}
```